# how to deploy different conf in different server without repeat the task each time

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

hy folks

I have to deploy configurations on several servers but they are different on each of them. I was wondering if with **ansible** it was possible to make a loop or I would pass in parameter the names of the servers. And when this match it deploys the configuration on the server?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can approach this, depending on your envirmonment:

- If you have a seperate file for each host you could name them something like "hostname.application.conf". Then you can use a simple copy to deploy the configs:

  ```
  - copy:
      src: "/path/to/configs/{{ansible_hostname}}.application.conf
      dest: path/to/application/folder/application.conf
  ```

  The variable "ansible_hostname" is automatically generated by ansible and contains the hostname of the currently targeted host. If you have multiple applications you can loop over them with someting like this:

  ```
  - copy
      src: "/path/to/configs/{{ansible_hostname}}.{{item.name}}.conf
      dest: "{{item.path}}{{item.name}}.conf
    ...
    loop: 
      - { name: 'appl1', path: '/path/to/application/folder/' }
      - ...
  ```
- If you have one configuration that needs to be modified and copied to the other hosts, you can look into templating: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html

Answer (score 0):

I woud Strongly recommend to use a Jinja2 template as the configuration file so Ansible can set the vars as described in group or host files.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html

Answer (score 0):

Role based Ansible Playbook

Will work based on  the following behaviors, for each role ‘x’:

If roles/x/tasks/main.yml exists, tasks listed therein will be added to the play.

If roles/x/handlers/main.yml exists, handlers listed therein will be added to the play.

If roles/x/vars/main.yml exists, variables listed therein will be added to the play.

If roles/x/defaults/main.yml exists, variables listed therein will be added to the play.

If roles/x/meta/main.yml exists, any role dependencies listed therein will be added to the list of roles

Any copy, script, template or include tasks (in the role) can reference files in roles/x/{files,templates,tasks}/ (dir depends on task) without having to path them relatively or absolutely.